# Building Suffix Array from Suffix Tree. Inorder visit when node has more than two children

Tags: algorithms, search-trees, suffix-trees, suffix-array

From the notes:

> It is not difficult to observe that the suffix array $\texttt{SA}$ of
> the text $\texttt{T}$ can be obtained from its suffix tree
> $\texttt{ST}$ by performing an in-order visit: each time a leaf is
> encountered, the suffix-index stored in this leaf is written into the
> suffix array $\texttt{SA}$; each time an internal node u is
> encountered, its associated value is written into the array
> $\texttt{lcp}$.

**How do you do the inorder visit when a node has more than two children?**

Let's say you visit the leftmost child, then the node, then the other leftmost child. Then do you visit again the node?

*SA* in an array of pointer to suffixes, ordered lexicographically.

*lcp* contains the longest common prefix between two consecutive suffixes $\text{suff}_{SA[i]} \text{ and } \text{suff}_{SA[i+1]}$.

The \$ represents a char that's smaller than every other char.

The value associated to each node is the length of the prefix spelled so far.

The leaves represents indices of suffixes. If T = banana\$, the leaf 3 represents nana\$ (T[3,7])

In the image there's what is supposed to be a suffix tree, but I think there's an error since the edges should be sorted according to their label and the leaf 7 with the edge labeled "\$" should be the leftmost leaf and edge.

[image]

When simulating the algorithm, first you visit the node 7 ( using the fixed version of the tree ), then the root, so you have

```
SA = [7, ...]
lcp = [0, ...]
```

Then let's say you keep going on with an inorder visit of u. **When you go back to the root, do you insert the value 0 again in the lcp**? Or do you do it just the first time you visited the root?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

If a node has $l$ children, with $l \geq 2$ during the inorder visit you have to treat the first $l-1$ children as left nodes, and you have to visit the parent multiple ($l-1$) times, writing multiple times the length of the prefix spelled inside the lcp array.

This, applied to the tree in the image, would yield the correct:

```
SA = [7, 6, 4, 2, 1, 5, 3]
lcp = [0, 1, 3, 0, 0, 2]
```

keeping in mind that the edge labeled "$" with the leaf 7 should be the leftmost.